# Remove substring in array of strings column in dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, string, dataframe, substring

I have dataframe column which is array of strings

`````
````
| fruits                         |
|--------------------------------|
|['fruit=apple', 'fruit=banana'] |
|['fruit=orange', 'fruit=banana']|
|['fruit=apple', 'fruit=orange'] |
|['fruit=orange', 'fruit=orange']|
````
`````

I want to get result like

```
``
| fruits             |
|--------------------|
|['apple', 'banana'] |
|['orange', 'banana']|
|['apple', 'orange'] |
|['orange', 'orange']|
``
```

I want to remove substring
`'fruit='`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a function to the column.  In this case split each string by `=` and take the last element of the result.

```
df['fruits'].apply(lambda x: [f.split('=')[-1] for f in x])
```